# C# Selenium: How to count elements and get selected option from a selection element

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using C# - Selenium Webdriver

I need to test a page that the number of selection elements is unknown. It might be one, two three... In the case example below, it contains 4 selections.

There are 2 issues here.

1. How to count the number of selection tags so that I can do a loop to get the selected option in each selection tags.
2. What's the correct syntax to get selected text with Selenium WebDriver C#?

Thank you.

```
<select name="ps_ck$0" id="ps_ck$0" >
    <option value="A">Active</option>
    <option value="C">Cancelled</option>
</select>

<select name="ps_ck$1" id="ps_ck$1" >
    <option value="A">Active</option>
    <option value="X">Cancelled</option>
</select>

<select name="ps_ck$2" id="ps_ck$2" >
    <option value="A">Active</option>
    <option value="X">Cancelled</option>
</select>

<select name="ps_ck$3" id="ps_ck$3" >
    <option value="A">Active</option>
    <option value="X">Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FindElements()` method and find all `select` elements by tag name. For every `select` element found, initialize the [`SelectElement`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm) class instance and get the value of [`SelectedOption` property](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement_SelectedOption.htm):

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("select"));

foreach (IWebElement select in selectElements)
{
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(select);
    Console.WriteLine(selectElement.SelectedOption.Text);
}
```

Note that we can be more specific when locating the `select` elements and check the `name` attribute to start with `ps_ck` using a *CSS selector*:

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("select[name^=ps_ck]"));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped a lot. But if possible, please edit this line: `Console.WriteLine(selectElement.SelectedOption);` This is not gonna work. It should be `Console.WriteLine(selectElement.SelectedOption.Text);` Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver C# code:

```
SelectElement SelectEmployeeName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ps_ck$0")));
//To count elements
IList<IWebElement> ElementCount = SelectEmployeeName.Options;
int NumberOfItems = ElementCount.Count;
Console.WriteLine("Size of BGL: " + NumberOfItems);
//Getting drop down values
for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfItems; i++)
{
String DropDownItems = ElementCount.ElementAt(i).Text;
Console.WriteLine(DropDownItems);
}
```

//Or Loop can be written as

```
foreach (IWebElement i in ElementCount)
{
String DropDownItems = i.Text;
Console.WriteLine(DropDownItems);
}
```